# c# Property set - Why use a private variable

Tags: c#, properties

I always see properties using a private variable to hold the value like this.

```
private int _myValue;
public int MyValue { get { return _myValue; } set { _myValue = value; } }
```

Why can't I just skip the private variable and do this...

```
public int MyValue { get { return MyValue; } set { MyValue = value; } }
```

*Note:  I didn't want to use auto properties because I was hoping to be able to do something like this.

```
public int MyValue { get { return MyValue.Tolower().Trim(); } set { MyValue = value; } }
```

Comment: Run your second version. When it explodes, you'll understand why.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind business case would require you to not adhere to the syntax of working C# properties?

Comment: Your note doesn't make sense. What you have proposed *is* auto-implemented properties.

Comment: Calling `ToLower()` on an `int` is the first problem you'll need to overcome ;)

Comment: @SheldonWarkentin, I call it *the legacy application business case* and *our managers simply don't understand how .NET works and don't want to take responsibility of recompiling the code in C# 3.0* business case. It's a pretty common business case seen in many enterprises.

Comment: @Adam Robinson - especially if it's a Turkish integer ;-)

Comment: @Thomas uh, yes it is. Maybe not syntactically correct; but exactly the same functionally.

Comment: Sounds like you are more asking why the c# compiler can't apply some syntactic sugar/cleverness to allow a variable with the name of a Property within the scope of the property declaration to point to an autogenerated backing field? I'd actually be interested in a reason why not myself (as in a reason why it is technically impossible rather than simply the answer "that is not how the language works" which is true but not as interesting)

Comment: @JohnKraft, accessors of auto implemented properties have no body, you can't put any logic in them...

Comment: @Thomas of course, now, the edits make this completely moot.

Comment: Why are you calling Tolower() on an integer?  There is no reason you cannot use your third method on the first example.  Of course your third example is wrong.

Comment: -1 for not trying it before asking the question.  simply executing the code would answer the question and crash the application with stack overflow exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the infinite loop would eventually cause a StackOverflowException to be thrown.

Comment: I'd consider infinite recursion to be one of many kinds of infinite loops.

Answer (score 5):

Because without a variable you'd end up with an [endless recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492689/c-sharp-property-set-why-use-a-private-variable), causing a [stack overflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx) :-)

```
public int MyValue
{
    get { return MyValue; }
    set { MyValue = value; }
}
```

Thus you need a *backing field*. The reason to keep the backing field `private` is to *hide the implementation details*. If it were public it wouldn't make any sense to declare a property to access it.

Comment: +1 for the great explanations in the link for endless recursion.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I just skip the private variable and do this...
>
> ```
>    public int MyValue { get { return MyValue; } set { MyValue = value; } }
> ```

Because `return MyValue` would recursively call the `get` accessor of the `MyValue` property, resulting in infinite recursion, and eventually a `StackOverflowException` (and similarly, `MyValue = value` would do the same with the `set` accessor)

Answer (score 0):

The getter and setters are there with a backing property in case you want to do some kind of validation.  If not then use auto properties, before auto properties were implemented this question came up and that's why they were implemented.

Comment: Maybe he is thinking about autoproperties I wonder if that's what he's wanting to use..

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier this would cause a stack overflow, the reason for that is that when you type MyValue = value you will be calling the set again in a infinit loop until the program runs out of stack space, and the same happens for the get.

```
public int MyValue { get { return MyValue; } set { MyValue = value; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

In additional to Ians response, they allow you to initialze the property to a default value of your choosing, rather than null:

```
private string _myString = string.Empty;

public string MyString
{
     get{ return _myString;}
     set{ _myString = value;}
}
```

will return string.Empty rather than null if the setter has never been called.